# How to import Python module in a package of the same name as the importing module?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following (project1 is on python path):

```
/project1/utils/utils.py
    def cool_function():
        print "cool"

/project1/backup/utils.py
    from utils.utils import cool_function
```

This throws "ImportError: No module named utils".

I assume this is because it is searching for utils.cool_function in backup.utils. Is there a rather than renaming the utils package? I think my naming convention makes sense, and is natural, so I'm reluctant to changing it. If that however is preferred and standard practice, I will rename it!

Thanks!

EDIT: I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `project1` is a package (parent dir is on `sys.path` and has an `__init__.py`), you can do `from project1.utils.utils import cool_function`. See also [PEP328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision), which is [new in python 2.5](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports). If you're using 2.5 or later, `from ..utils.utils import cool_function` may also work.

Comment: I also think this is a good way to do it. Use project1 to differentiate between; project1.utils.utils and project1.backup.utils. If project1 is in sys.path as you say this will also help if you will want to run the project from some other folder like: python folder1/folder2/project1/run.py

Comment: Actually, /project1/ is on the path, so I can refer to backup or utils directly when importing. Should put them in a wrapper package?

Comment: In many cases it's a judgement call, but as a general rule I'd say yes - if you ever need to integrate this project with others, it'd be problem if they also have 'utils' or 'backup' top-level packages. That generally doesn't happen - but it's for this reason.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. I've moved everything into a super package and I already feel better about it. Everything is imported using the root package name (e.g. project1.utils.utils) as suggested, and it all works now. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

```
from ..utils.utils import cool_function
```

Comment: This doesnt work! Not sure why, I did try it myself before posting to SO.

Comment: I tried with Python27 and get  "ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package"

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with me.

With the following project structure:

```
project/
|-- run.py
`-- utils
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- utils.py
|-- backup
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- utils.py
```

Where you call `python3 run.py` from the `project` directory.

**Edit:** Sorry I just saw that this does not apply to `python-2.x`.